# Rsync -what have I forgotten

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, rsync

I just added a new ubuntu9.04 desktop machine to my network.
Using rsnapshot (scriptontop of rsync) to backup all the machines.
But I'm getting denied error on the new machine.

The system works perfectly with the other Ubuntu and windows machines.
I can list the shares on the new machine so rsyncd and the network is ok.
I have the same rsycnd.conf and rsyncd.secrets files and they have the same permissions.
The log on the client just says "rsync denied"
Rsnapshot is using a dummy user that doesn't exist on any of the client machines

Obviously I have done something on the existing Ubuntu machines to make them work - but I have no idea what!

eg.

```
rsync rsync://backup@192.168.0.100:/home --password-file=secrets
```

Works for the old machine, gives permission denied on ".101"

Comment: Are you sure rsync can access the local data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the rsyncd.conf from the working system to the none-working one and it worked.

Probably rsync is fussy about tabs vs spaces or trailing spaces in config files?

Comment: why don't you just run diff on the two config files?

Comment: They were on different machines and it didn't occur to me that this was the problem - I thought there was some security setting somewhere that I had set on the old machine and forgotten about.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Ubuntu 9.04 has AppArmor. This simply means that there are more security restrictions in place. Perhaps this is what you are running into?